# F0321 01:22:08.021044 18633 math_functions.cpp:250] Check failed: a <= b (0 vs. -1.19209e-07)

Tags: python, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to retrain caffe SSD Mobilenet model and I face this problem 
any advices ?
here is full report

```
    I0321 01:22:07.921737 18611 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer conv0
I0321 01:22:07.921798 18611 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer conv0
0
'I0321 01:22:07.921808 18611 net.cpp:408] conv0 -> conv0'

    I0321 01:22:07.921802 18611 net.cpp:434] conv0 <- data_data_0_split_

F0321 01:22:08.021044 18633 math_functions.cpp:250] Check failed: a <= b (0 vs. -1.19209e-07)
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment line 250 in src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp:

> ```
> // CHECK_LE(a, b);
> ```

and then recompile pycaffe with

make py